# Unable to create the storage plugin for hive in Apache drill

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, apache-drill, bigdata

I am new to Apache drill.While creating the storage plugin for Apache hive.I am getting the error.I have tried two ways.Below is the configuration.

1.First approach:

```
        {
          "type": "hive",
          "enabled": false,
          "configProps": {
        "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift2:localhost:10000",
        "fs.default.name": "hdfs://localhost:9000/",
        "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
          }
        }
```

2.Second approach:

```
        {
          "type": "hive",
          "enabled": false,
          "configProps": {
        "hive.metastore.uris": "",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true",
        "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "/user/tmp/warehouse/hive",
        "fs.default.name": "hdfs://localhost:9000",
        "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
          }
        }
```

I am using plain Apache components and both drill and hive2 are installed in the same machine.

For both the cases I am getting the error in the GUI as

```
Please retry: error (unable to create/ update storage)
```

Kindly help me in resolving the same.Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Did you find anything in `drillbit.log` and `drillbit.out` in `<drill-directory>/log` when error pop up in GUI?  Are you clear on both of your approach? First one, you are running hive metastore as a separate service (_outside hive_)  and in the second aproach, metadata is embedded with hive.

Comment: No, there is no file generated with drillbit.log or out.I have verified in the drill directory also. Actually, I wanted to access all the databases and the tables that are present inside the hive metastore, which means that I wanted to run as a service as far my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to connection through the first approach i.e Hive Remote Metastore Connection.

Here is the Configuration:

```
    {
      "type": "hive",
      "enabled": false,
      "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift:localhost:9083",
    "fs.default.name": "hdfs://localhost:9000/",
    "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
      }
    }
```

Also make sure that Hive metastore is up and running.It can be started using the below command

```
hive -- service metastore &.
```

Also the parameter `hive.metastore.uris` in the `hive-site.xml` should be updated with `thrift://localhost:9083`.

Thanks